# How can we run the selenium tests on different machines without giving the manual configurations to the nodes

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I would like to run the test on different machines. But I don't want to set the manual configurations to the nodes and I want the hub to take control on the nodes.

Please help me on this

Comment: Can you at least let us know what have you tried already?